# Return some array elements based on their index

Tags: c#

I have a weirdly-made JSON that I need to deserialize.
It looks like this:

```
{
    "Properties": [
        { "A": "aaa", "B": "bbb", "C": "ccc" },
        { "X": "xxx", "Y": "yyy" },
        { "many other": "items" }
    ],
    "Products": [
        { "Id": 0, "PropertiesIndexes": [ 0, 1 ] },
        { "Id": 1, "PropertiesIndexes": [ 0, 1, 2 ] }
    ]
}
```

The properties array can have objects with any number and name of keys, and each product accesses the properties array through an index.

We need to store these JSON files in MongoDB, and because they can be quite huge (I'm talking several hundred Mb for a file) I need to split them (Mongo has a 16Mb limit). So, each property is a Mongo document, and each product is a Mongo document.
Because I can't just get properties in the order of insertion, we have decided to save all the properties of each product.

Here are the classes used to deserialize this data (using JSON.Net):

```
public class Entity {
    public OrderedDictionary Properties { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }

    publid int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] PropertiesIndexes { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need to access the actual properties data directly from the product, so that a (hypothetical) resulting JSON would be like this:

```
{
    "Products": [
        { "Id": 0,
          "PropertiesData": [
                { "A": "aaa", "B": "bbb", "C": "ccc" },
                { "X": "xxx", "Y": "yyy" }
            ]
        },
        { "Id": 1,
          "PropertiesData": [
                { "A": "aaa", "B": "bbb", "C": "ccc" },
                { "X": "xxx", "Y": "yyy" },
                { "many other": "items" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My naïve implementation is this:

```
// in Product
[JsonIgnore]
public IDictionary<string, object> PropertiesData {
    get {
        if (this.Entity != null && this.Entity.Properties != null) {
            var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.PropertiesIndexes.Length; i++) {
                data.Add(
                    this.Entity.Properties.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(this.PropertiesIndexes[i]).Key.ToString(),
                    this.Entity.Properties[this.PropertiesIndexes[i]]);
            }

            return data;
        }

        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

but it's slow (as I said, I have huge amounts of data) and very ugly.

Back when we were using `ExpandoObject`s I had a nice, fast and memory-efficient yeilding method:

```
private IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> getPropertiesDataFromEntity() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.PropertiesIndexes.Count; i++) {
        yield return this.Entity.Properties[this.PropertiesIndexes[i]];
    }
}
```

but `ExpandoObject` have problems of their own in the context of our app: they are not always properly saved in Mongo, and they are not serialized by WCF without a custom serializer.

Comment: Take a step back and think if you really need a sorted dictionary for this. If you are accessing items by their indexes, you might be better off with an indexed collection such as a simple list or array. A dictionary is not designed for index-based element access but for key-based element access which is much faster.

Comment: Actually it's the result of deserialization. I have edited the post to provide more context, to explain why I've come up with this. If you think another solution would be better, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Let me see if I understand your json: Product with id 0 will have properties `{ "X": "xxx", "Y": "yyy" }` and properties from the 6th object in the properties array which you didn't include, and product with id 1 will have properties `{ "X": "xxx", "Y": "yyy" }`, as well as properties from the 4th and 11th element in the properties array (assuming indexes starts from 0, meaning that `{ "A": "aaa", "B": "bbb", "C": "ccc" }` is index 0). Is that correct?

Comment: I have updated my question to add a sample of the resulting data I want (with existing indexes :-P ).

Answer (score 1):

I've written something quite simple to get from your source JSON to your target JSON.
It includes 4 very simple classes.

The first two are designed to be deserialized from your source JSON:

```
public class Source
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] Properties { get; set; }

    public SourceProduct[] Products { get; set; }

}

public class SourceProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int[] PropertiesIndexes { get; set; }
}
```

The third class is the target product:

```
public class Product
{
    private List<Dictionary<string, string>> _propertiesData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> PropertiesData { get { return _propertiesData; } }
}
```

And the last class is the final target, where I am translating the data from the source to target:

```
public class Target
{
    private List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get { return _products; } }

    public Target(Source source)
    {
        foreach(var sourceProduct in source.Products)
        {
            var product = new Product()
            {
                Id = sourceProduct.Id

            };
            foreach(var propertyIndex in sourceProduct.PropertiesIndexes)
            {
                product.PropertiesData.Add(source.Properties[propertyIndex]);
            }
            _products.Add(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Using these classes your client code simply becomes this:

```
var targetJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
    (
        new Target(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source>(sourceJson))
    );
```